# Removing Images from a WordPress Post

Tags: images, post-content

I wanted to remove the images from a WordPress post to give me more control of how I could layout the design for the front page of a website. After doing some messing around and failing, I finally found a great post which had an amazing little piece of code that solved my problem.

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $post->post_content);
echo $postOutput;
?>
```

But some time i have link above images like:

```
<a href="#"><img src="PATH_IMAGES"></a>
```

So, How can remove it?

Comment: Just like you did, but with different regex. This looks like a pure PHP question to me and as such is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete_attachment( $attachment_id, true );
wp_delete_post( $attachment_id, true );
```

Are your best friends. You will need something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'  => null,
    'post_status'  => null,
    'post_parent'  => $post->ID,
    'post__not_in' => array(
        get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )
    ),
);
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        delete_attachment( $attachment_id, true );
        wp_delete_post( $attachment_id, true );
    }
}
```

The "true" statement defines that the attachments and their IDs are completely removed from the backend and filesystem. If you want to store them into the trash, then set it to false.